Error: Unknown authentication strategy "google" in Passport.js OAuth Setup
I'm trying to implement Google OAuth in my Node.js application using Passport.js, but I keep getting the following error when accessing the /auth/google route:
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "google"
    at attempt (/path/to/project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:193:39)
    at authenticate (/path/to/project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:379:7)
    ...

I've already set up my GoogleStrategy and initialized Passport, but something seems to be missing. Below are the relevant files.
auth.ts (Passport Configuration)
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";
import User from "../models/user.model";  // Mongoose User model

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
        if (!user) {
          user = await User.create({
            googleId: profile.id,
            email: profile.emails![0].value,
            displayName: profile.displayName,
            profilePic: profile.photos![0].value,
          });
        }
        done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        done(error, undefined);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user: any, done) => done(null, user._id));
passport.deserializeUser(async (id: string, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error, null);
  }
});

export default passport;

app.ts (Main Server File)
import express from "express";
import helmet from "helmet";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import session from "express-session";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import passport from "./auth";  // Importing the configured Passport instance
import authRoute from "./routes/auth";  // Auth routes

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET!,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI! }),
    cookie: {
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
    },
  })
);

// Initialize Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// MongoDB Connection
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI!)
  .then(() => console.log("Mongodb connected successfully"))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

// Routes
app.use("/auth", authRoute);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port} http://localhost:${port}`);
});

auth.ts (Router)
import express from "express";
import passport from "../auth";  // Using the same Passport instance

const router = express.Router();

router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/dashboard`);
  }
);

export default router;

Packages Installed:
"dependencies": {
    "connect-mongo": "^5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "express-session": "^1.18.1",
    "helmet": "^8.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.7.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.9",
    "@types/node": "^22.8.1",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.17",
    "@types/passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.16",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }

I’ve verified that:

Google OAuth strategy is registered before routes are used.
The same passport instance is being used across the app.
All necessary packages are installed.
All my env secrets are correct

I've also restarted the server multiple times but the error persists.
Double-checked the environment variables.
Ensured only one instance of passport is being used.
Verified the MongoDB connection and session configuration.
Why am I getting the Unknown authentication strategy "google" error, and how can I fix it?

The error was due to not importing the Passport configuration file in app.ts. Passport strategies need to be registered before you use them, which means the file where you set up your Google OAuth strategy (in this case, config/passport.ts) must be imported in app.ts.
Simply adding this line to app.ts fixed the issue:
import "./config/passport";

This ensures that the Google strategy is registered with Passport before the routes try to use it. Now, Passport recognizes the "google" strategy, and the error

Unknown authentication strategy "google"

no longer appears.
Final app.ts File
import express from "express";
import helmet from "helmet";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import passport from "passport";
import session from "express-session";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import authRoute from "./routes/auth";

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

import "./config/passport";


app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    credentials: true,
  })
);

// mongodb connection
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI!)
  .then(() => console.log("Mongodb connected successfully"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET!,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI! }),
    cookie: {
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
    },
  })
);

// initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/auth", authRoute);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port} http://localhost:${port}`);
});

This import statement ensures that the strategy is registered, and now the authentication strategy works as expected.
